# Spring bean to represent a Table

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

This is how we can represent a map in Spring beans

```
<bean id="MyBean" class="org.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg name="componentName">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="T1" value-ref="A"/>
            <entry key="T2" value-ref="B"/>
            <entry key="T3" value-ref="C"/>
        </util:map>
</bean>
```

For this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(Map<String, String> componentName)
}
```

How would I represent a class that needs a Table instead of a Map as input.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Table;

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(Table<String, String, String> componentName)
}
```

I would also like to understand how this can be extended for more complex structures like a class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Only four major collection types are supported.

```
List – <list/>
Set – <set/>
Map – <map/>
Properties – <props/>
```

From Docs,

> In the list, set, map, and props elements, you set the properties and arguments of the Java Collection types List, Set, Map, and Properties, respectively.

Spring Doc Ref [7.4.2] : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class